# How to input twitter data (csv/txt) into DBSCAN python?

Tags: python, numpy, dbscan

Could someone guide me how could i cluster twitter data using DBSCAN in python? I am totally new to DBSCAN. Also, how to determine the eps value and the iloc or loc value.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.cluster import DBSCAN
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler


def clusterEvaluate(cluster):
count_cluster = np.bincount(cluster)
count_cluster = np.argmax(count_cluster) 

same_clusters = np.count_nonzero(cluster == count_cluster)/np.size(cluster)
return same_clusters



dataset = np.loadtxt('tweetdata.csv') # not sure if this works
X = StandardScaler().fit_transform(dataset)

y_valid = dataset.iloc[:6].values()

dbscan = DBSCAN(eps= 0.5,min_samples=5,metric='euclidean')

y = dbscan.fit_predict(X)

cluster_labels = np.unique(y)


same_clusters = []
i = 0

for index in cluster_labels:
   cluster = y_valid[y == index]
   same_clusters.insert((i, clusterEvaluate(cluster)))
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to choose and appropriate data representation *and* distance function for this. Furthermore, scalability will kill you.

I do not think it will work well. I have it seen anything that gives insightful results beyond counting frequent words in a unnecessary complex fashion. Twitter data is a bitch. The messages are just too short. All the good approaches like LDA need much longer documents.